# How to preselect 'Simple Product' type on product grid

Tags: simple-product, product-grid

I always select 'Simple Product' (product type) on product grid page before I search any product to see only simple product , not group or other type

How to make the 'Simple Product' is already selected whenever I visit product grid page as default?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding

```
setDefaultFilter('fieldName'=>'FieldValue')
```

at class catalog grid class  `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid` at `_construct()` function;

As you want to  **simple product as default filter** then try thus:

```
 $this->setDefaultFilter(array('type'=>'simple'));
```

Comment: it is not working.!

Comment: Can you explain more detail for store owner to be able to understand..? like what file I have to edit Thanks!

Comment: silly mistake type_id  should be type.. it works

Comment: lol. Good work though. +1 for your answer,

Comment: john, i cannot understand what explain. you need.. it guess that question will give you full answer